# Unexpected "=" in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In my code, I get the error message saying that there is an unexpected "=". I have tried running the line without certain "=", but that only causes other error messages, like "unused arguments". This is supposed to help, along with the rest of the code, with making a plot easier to read.

Here is the line of code:

```r
Tricep.peaks <- data.frame (findpeaks(Tricep_falt, npeaks=8, minpeaksheight=.01, minpeaksdistance=freq=5))
```

Here is the error message:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "Tricep.peaks <- data.frame (findpeaks(Tricep_falt, npeaks=8, minpeaksheight=.01, minpeaksdistance=freq="

Packages running are, signal, zoo, matlab, ggplot2, pracma, purrr, dplyr

Comment: Trry `minpeaksdistance=5)`.  Not clear from which package you got the function `findpeaks`

Comment: Here is the error code for unused arguments: "Error in findpeaks(Tricep_falt, npeaks = 8, minpeaksheight = 0.01, minpeaksdistancefreq = 5) : 
  unused arguments (minpeaksheight = 0.01, minpeaksdistancefreq = 5)"

Comment: Please update your post with the packages used.  I can't find `findpeaks` function

Comment: The `findpeaks()` function is from the `pracma` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message shows, the error is caused by `minpeaksdistance=freq=5` which looks like a typo to me.

According to https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/findpeaks, the parameter is called `minpeakdistance` but not `minpeaksdistance`.

The OP probably meant `minpeakdistance=5` or `minpeakdistance=freq`.

Comment: I tried 'minpeaksdistance=5' and i got 'Error in findpeaks(Tricep_falt, npeaks = 8, minpeaksheight = 0.01, minpeaksdistance = 5) : 
  unused arguments (minpeaksheight = 0.01, minpeaksdistance = 5)' as a response

Comment: The parameters are called `minpeakheight` and `minpeakdistance`, resp.